# Using Compass/sass for percentage width responsive layouts?

Tags: sass, responsive-design, compass-sass

I am trying to use Sass (and Compass) to simplify the creation of a percentage-width layout.

Using the formula from A List Apart  of `target/context=result`, where the context is 980px and the design width is 640px, I tried doing a rule of

```
#leftcol {
width: ((640/980)*100%);
}
```

Which compiles to

```
#leftcol {
  width: 65.306%;
}
```

Is there an easier way than to do that without typing that over and over?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No mixin needed. Sass has a built-in percentage function that accepts a variety of units.

```
width: percentage(640 / 980)
width: percentage(640px / 980px)
```

both result in:

```
width: 65.30612%
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, I made a mixin:

```
@mixin flex($target, $context){
width: (($target/$context)*100%);
}
```

and then use it

```
#leftcol {
@include flex(640, 980);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sass also allows function definition (so you could use e.g. w/ min-width as well as width, or as part of other subexpression):

```
@function flex-width($target, $context) {
    @return (($target/$context)*100%);
}

#leftcol {
    width: flex-width(640, 980);
}
```